# Disable Excel Data Connections Properties

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, database

We have spreadsheets hooked up to our database through the network. The only thing is the data connection requires a login to the database by an administrator. We have other people that need to view the spreadsheets and refresh the data connections.

While it does have the functionality to save a password, people can go in and look at the database connection and see the password with no mask or anything. **Is there a way to lock the sheet so that a user can't go in and look at the data connection string?** You can lock it so that a user can't edit it, but they can still see the password.

Comment: "The only thing is the data connection requires a login to the database by an administrator" This is a horrible practice.  Why not make a read-only user in SQL, and then use that as the user in Excel? That way it doesn't matter if the know the password...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 tell me about it... I tried setting the permission in our database, but it still asks for a username and password and still requires it to be the admin..

Comment: Maybe ask another question on how to set up a readonly user on your database, because I agree with @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, that's the way to go. If you do ask another question, include the database type and version.